# Show table structure and list of tables in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I had employed MySQL for a couple of former projects. But now have 
decided to switch to PostgreSQL. Not that version 8 also works on that, 
ahem other OS which I'm stuck with at work.

But alas, two of the most useful commands appear to be missing:

- `SHOW TABLES`
- `DESCRIBE table`

Inasmuch as my prototyping DB is on my NetBSD server at home while my 
data waiting to be 'based is at work, such that I have to connect via 
Perl/DBI and XML-RPC (not psql, alas). The IT dept here just says, "Use 
MS-Access", so no help there.

While I'm in the initial stage I need an informative way to blunder 
around and see what's what as I try different ways to build this thing. 
For that I had always relied on the two above from MySQL.

I can't believe there is no way for PostgreSQL to tell me what the 
current DB's table structure is via simple SQL queries executed remotely.

Surely there must be. But I can't seem to find out from the couple of 
books I have. All I dug up was some ultra-lame hack to get column names 
for an already known table name by doing a "WHERE 1 != 1" or some such 
so that no actual rows could be returned. Not very informative, that. 
Surely I've missed the point, somewhere.

So enlighten me, please. What, pray tell, are the PostgreSQL-ish SQL 
queries one uses so as to explore a given DB's table structure? What is 
the PostgreSQL translation for "SHOW TABLES" and "DESCRIBE table"?

Comment: There are some cross-DBMS tools that will do exactly that for you. Check out the Postgres Wiki: http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Community_Guide_to_PostgreSQL_GUI_Tools

Answer (score 52, accepted):

As per the [Documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html)

```
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name as show_tables
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
```

for more convenience make it as a *function*

```
create or replace function show_tables() returns SETOF text as $$
SELECT
    table_schema || '.' || table_name as show_tables
FROM
    information_schema.tables
WHERE
    table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
AND
    table_schema NOT IN ('pg_catalog', 'information_schema');
$$
language sql;
```

So we can get the *tables* using

```
select show_tables()
```

---

For the *table description*

```
 select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
 from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name ='table_name';
```

as a *Function*

```
create or replace function describe_table(tbl_name text) returns table(column_name   
varchar, data_type varchar,character_maximum_length int) as $$
select column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where table_name = $1;
$$
language 'sql';

select  *  from describe_table('a_table_name');
```

Answer (score 120):

`SHOW TABLES` and `DESCRIBE TABLE` are MySQL-specific admin commands, and nothing to do with standard SQL.

You want the:

```
\d
```

and

```
\d+ tablename
```

commands from `psql`.

These are implemented client-side. I find this odd myself, and would love to move them server-side as built-in SQL commands one day.

Other clients provide other ways to browse the structure - for example, PgAdmin-III.

If you want a portable way to get table structure in code, you should use the `information_schema` views, which are SQL-standard. See [`information_schema`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/information-schema.html). They're available in MySQL, PostgreSQL, Ms-SQL, and most other DBs. The downside is that they're fiddlier to use, so they aren't convenient for quick access when you're just browsing a DB structure.

Comment: by the way are there proper type on sql like $this->db->query("DESCRIBE accounts"); something like this on a query version it is okay on the command but rather when you code on it.

Comment: @user560756 That makes absolutely no sense, but if you mean "how do I show the table structure from Perl DBI or some other client" the answer is "use the `information_schema`", which is the standard way. See `information_schema.tables`, `information_schema.columns`, etc. This works in MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS-SQL, etc etc etc.

Comment: I also want to add that it should be better "tablename" or "Tablename" because if your table has uppercase letters it will not find it otherwise.

Also the error will be: Did not find any relation named "Tablename" - as you typed it, preserving the case. Thus very hard to figure out what went wrong.