# Amend the value of a row

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I am trying to amend the value of a key in a table.

I have a database (this is for Immich if relevant). See below details of the table. I am trying to amend "library.watch.usePolling" from "true" to "false". I am using this command and getting an error. I am not sure, what this error means, nor whether I am using the correct command. I know this must be an easy question, but I am very much a beginner with PostgreSQL.

```sql
UPDATE system_config
SET value = false
WHERE key = library.watch.usePolling
;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "watch"
LINE 3: WHERE key = library.watch.usePolling
```

These are the details of the table in the database as it currently exists.

```
\d+ system_config
                                               Table "public.system_config"
     Column |       Type        | Collation | Nullable | Default | Storage  | Compression | Stats target | Description 
    --------+-------------------+-----------+----------+---------+----------+-------------+--------------+-------------
     key    | character varying |           | not null |         | extended |             |              | 
     value  | character varying |           |          |         | extended |             |              | 
    Indexes:
        "PK_aab69295b445016f56731f4d535" PRIMARY KEY, btree (key)
    Access method: heap
```

```
SELECT * from "system_config"; 
                 key                 |     value     
-------------------------------------+---------------
 ffmpeg.transcode                    | "disabled"
 job.objectTagging.concurrency       | 4
 job.clipEncoding.concurrency        | 4
 job.sidecar.concurrency             | 4
 job.migration.concurrency           | 4
 job.library.concurrency             | 80
 job.thumbnailGeneration.concurrency | 20
 job.metadataExtraction.concurrency  | 50
 job.recognizeFaces.concurrency      | 6
 storageTemplate.enabled             | true
 ffmpeg.accel                        | "qsv"
 library.scan.cronExpression         | "0 */6 * * *"
 job.smartSearch.concurrency         | 60
 job.faceDetection.concurrency       | 60
 library.watch.enabled               | true
 library.watch.usePolling            | true
(16 rows)
```

Note: I have also tried this command:

```
SET "system_config.value" = "false" WHERE "system_config.key" = "library.watch.usePolling";
```

I've tried a few options. Main ones here:

```sql
UPDATE system_config
SET value = false
WHERE key = library.watch.usePolling
;
ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "watch"
LINE 3: WHERE key = library.watch.usePolling
```

and

```
SET "system_config.value" = "false" WHERE "system_config.key" = "library.watch.usePolling";
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "WHERE"
LINE 1: SET "system_config.value" = "false" WHERE "system_config.key...
```

Comment: Please provide the DDL for the creation of your system_config table - the more information you provide (in the question itself), the more likely you are to obtain a decent answer!

Comment: I didn't create the table. the table only has two columns and the output of which is in the above.

Comment: I have now added more details of the table as suggested over here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/tags/postgresql-performance/info

Comment: Text values should be in single quotes: `'library.watch.usePolling'` as should dates etc. Most programming languages will expect some sort of quoting for text. Note that you do NOT want double-quotes, they are used for identifiers (table, column-names etc) that contain punctuation, spaces or need case to be preserved.

Comment: @rwattstci - check out my revised answer.

Answer (score 0):

For starters, I wouldn't use either `key` or `value` as field names - if you look [here](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/coding-standards/list-of-sql-reserved-words), you will see that both words occur in that list. They also appear in the PostgreSQL [list](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (but as non-reserved) - again, avoid any words on this list - belt and braces! I would recommend that you change the names of your fields to (something like) `sc_key` and `sc_value` - these are also more meaningful.

All of the code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/UHhYjW07).

From [here](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-rename-column/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html)):

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
RENAME COLUMN column_name TO new_column_name;
```

so,

```
ALTER TABLE system_config
RENAME COLUMN key TO sc_key;
```

and the same for `value`.

Also, [rename](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/971786/constraint-name-update-in-postgresql) - ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-altertable.html) - search for `RENAME CONSTRAINT`) that `PRIMARY KEY` - an error message telling a user that there has been a violation of `PK_aab69295b445016f56731f4d535` is absolutely meaningless - change it to something like `sc_pk` (or `system_config_pk`).

BTW, there is **never** any need to (double) quote your identifiers (e.g. table, column or constraint) names **unless** for some reason, you wish to, (and/or) are obliged to, respect case, punctuation or spaces in identifiers.

If not, my **strong** recommendation is to use snake_case for everything (lower case with underscores separating words to make it readable). There are various SQL style guides on the internet ([this one](https://www.sqlstyle.guide/) is good) - but pick a style and **stick to it** - consistency in this area helps legibility and makes debugging easier. I would also **never** put punctuation or spaces in my identifier names - you're just making life difficult for yourself by doing this - it also means that in the event of a change of database server, your code will be less- or completely non-portable!

Run a couple of queries to double check our changes (found code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25640156/470530) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9985338/470530)) - column names:

```
SELECT column_name, data_type, character_maximum_length
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_name ='system_config';
```

Result:

```
column_name  data_type          character_maximum_length
sc_key       character varying                      null
sc_value     character varying                      null
```

the `null` is because there is no length specified - a `VARCHAR` can be up to 1GB.

and `PRIMARY KEY`:

```
SELECT c.column_name, c.data_type
FROM information_schema.table_constraints tc 
JOIN information_schema.constraint_column_usage AS ccu USING (constraint_schema, constraint_name) 
JOIN information_schema.columns AS c ON c.table_schema = tc.constraint_schema
  AND tc.table_name = c.table_name AND ccu.column_name = c.column_name
WHERE constraint_type = 'PRIMARY KEY' and tc.table_name = 'system_config';
```

Result:

```
column_name   data_type
sc_key        character varying
```

Now, to your question proper.

Double quotes are used for identifiers (table and column names) - to specify a string (in this case `CHARACTER VARYING`), you use **single quotes**!

To resolve your issue, I did the following:

I created and then modified the table as specified above (see fiddle), and then I inserted your data:

```
INSERT INTO system_config VALUES
('ffmpeg.transcode'                    , 'disabled'),
('job.objectTagging.concurrency'       , 4),
('job.clipEncoding.concurrency'        , 4),
('job.sidecar.concurrency'             , 4),
('job.migration.concurrency'           , 4),
('job.library.concurrency'             , 80),
('job.thumbnailGeneration.concurrency' , 20),
('job.metadataExtraction.concurrency'  , 50),
('job.recognizeFaces.concurrency'      , 6),
('storageTemplate.enabled'             , true),
('ffmpeg.accel'                        , 'qsv'),
('library.scan.cronExpression'         , '0 */6 * * *'),
('job.smartSearch.concurrency'         , 60),
('job.faceDetection.concurrency'       , 60),
('library.watch.enabled'               , true),
('library.watch.usePolling'            , true);
```

Note the use of **single quotes** to delineate strings - PostgreSQL appears to recognise numbers and true as valid strings (which surprised me, I must confess).

See the query using the [`PG_TYPEOF()`](https://www.commandprompt.com/education/how-to-get-the-column-type-using-pg_typeof-function-in-postgresql/) function in the fiddle - they all come out as `CHARACTER VARYING`.

```
SELECT
  sc_key, sc_value, PG_TYPEOF(sc_key), PG_TYPEOF(sc_value)
FROM
  system_config;
```

Result (sample):

```
sc_key                         sc_value  pg_typeof          pg_typeof
ffmpeg.transcode               disabled  character varying  character varying
job.objectTagging.concurrency         4  character varying  character varying
job.clipEncoding.concurrency          4  character varying  character varying
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

So, now to modify the value of `library.watch.usePolling`.

```
UPDATE system_config
SET sc_value = 'false'   -- also works with just false (no single quotes)
WHERE sc_key = 'library.watch.usePolling';
```

and again, we check:

```
SELECT
  sc_key, sc_value
FROM
  system_config
WHERE
  sc_key = 'library.watch.usePolling';
```

Result:

```
sc_key                    sc_value
library.watch.usePolling     false
```

So, you have to be careful to distinguish between double quotes for identifiers and single quotes for delineating strings!

On a final note, unless there's a compelling reason not to do so, I would always use the `TEXT` datatype (maximum size also 1GB) for any sort of, well..., text data. From here:

> Generally, there is no downside to using text in terms of
> performance/memory. On the contrary: text is the optimum. Other types
> have more or less relevant downsides. text is literally the
> "preferred" type among string types in the Postgres type system, which
> can affect function or operator type resolution.

See the fiddle for this query:

```
SELECT 
  typname, typlen, typispreferred
FROM
  pg_type
WHERE 
  typname IN ('char', 'text', 'varchar', 'cstring');
```

Result:

```
typname  typlen  typispreferred
char          1               f
text         -1               t
varchar      -1               f
cstring      -2               f
```

So, we see that `TEXT` is indeed the preferred type when it comes to character/text data.

And from the same post (read it in full - and follow up on the links - all of this poster's contributions are very instructive):

> I rarely use anything but text for character data in Postgres.

Check out the poster's rep - so my final piece of advice is to [change your column types](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-tutorial/postgresql-change-column-type/) ([manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/16/sql-altertable.html)) to `TEXT` rather than `VARCHAR`/`CHARACTER VARYING`.

```
ALTER TABLE system_config
ALTER COLUMN sc_key
SET DATA TYPE TEXT;
```

and the same for `sc_value`.

Check using the `PG_TYPEOF()` query from before - result (sample):

```
sc_key                        sc_value  pg_typeof  pg_typeof
ffmpeg.transcode              disabled       text       text
job.objectTagging.concurrency        4       text       text
job.clipEncoding.concurrency         4       text       text
...
... snipped for brevity
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I actually didnt need to amend the value at all - so deleting the value from the table was all I needed.

solution:

```
SELECT * FROM system_config WHERE system_config.key = 'library.watch.enabled';
```

then

```
DELETE FROM system_config WHERE system_config.key = 'library.watch.enabled';
```